# Getting: error that Gulp Pump requires 2 streams

Tags: javascript, gulp

having an issue when running my gulp build, my pump package sends an error call back.

Error: pump requires two streams per minimum

I did further digging and in the index.js of the package any streams < 2 print out the above.

my code is below

```
gulp.task('build', ['compress', 'compileSass'], function(){
        pump([
         //Source of problem 
            gulp.dest('dist')
        ]);
        return gulp.src(['css/bootstrap.css',
                        'js/app.min.js',
                        './index.html'],
                        { base: './' });
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue... why in the hell is this enforced, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: In your case, I think you want to have the gulp.src line inside the pump block, and before the gulp.dest() line.

Comment: Hey there, i fixed this a while ago but forgot to update, basically i move my project folder to another location so i just deleted my node modules folder and ran npm install. After that it fixed everything . hope it helps

Comment: ah ok, you can answer your own question then, and someone someday might find it helpful. and i think you get points for it.

Comment: this seems like i might actually have the same problem, so i'm going to try this now.

Comment: Cool thanks for letting me know and did it work?

Comment: i don't know, i can't get to it right now. but i'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically I had moved my project to another folder which messed up node modules folder. I simply deleted the node modules folder and ran 
**npm install**